# What is a good program to record from a webcam in Linux?

Tags: linux, webcam

I've found `luvcview`, but it's not that good for recording. It doesn't get audio from the mic input of either the webcam or just the regular computer microphones. Also, in my case with the Logitech 9000, the video plays a few FPS slower than it was recorded.

**Does anyone know of a program in Linux that's good for webcam recording?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cheese](http://projects.gnome.org/cheese/)  is a photobooth type application that also records videos. It make already be installed (if you use Gnome). Not sure if it will solve your audio/frame-rate problem, but it's worth a try.

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) is the everything-video-program. While it may not be as straight forward as other apps for what you want to do, running the 'convert/save' wizard should guide you through the process. You may (or will) need to play with the options to get the format/quality you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah Cheese is pretty good. Nice and simple, and records sound and synchronizes it properly. It displays the video at the wrong aspect ratio, but saves the video properly when recording, so not a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with [**MEncoder**](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html) by pointing it to your video device.

Example:

```
mencoder tv:// -tv driver=v4l:width=320:height=240:device=/dev/video0 -ovc lavc -o vid.avi
```

Comment: And it's always great to have the command-line version.